# iOS16 SwiftUI app crashes when trying to create view using loop

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ios16

I've defined a view in SwiftUI which takes an Int array and is supposed to display the elements of the array in a VStack such that every "full row" contains three elements of the array and then the last "row" contains the remainder of elements. When running the app on iOS16 I get "Fatal error: Can't remove first element from an empty collection" for the call `let die = dice.removeFirst()` (also when passing in a non-empty array of course). I've tried following the debugger but I don't understand the way it jumps around through the loops.

On iOS15 this code worked fine. In the actual program I don't display the array content as Text but I have images associated with each Int between 1 and 6 which I display. I replaced this with Text for simplicity's sake.

Thanks for any help!

```
struct DiceOnTableView: View {
    let diceArray: [Int]
    
    var body: some View {
        let fullRows: Int = diceArray.count / 3
        let diceInLastRow: Int = diceArray.count % 3
        var dice: [Int] = diceArray
        
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<fullRows, id: \.self) { row in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<3) { column in
                        let die = dice.removeFirst()
                        Text("\(die)")
                    }
                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<diceInLastRow, id: \.self) { column in
                    let die = dice.removeFirst()
                    Text("\(die)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the `diceArray` is modified without redrawing the view. Do you really need to call `removeFirst` to get the value for `die`? Have you tried to calculate the proper index of the element and use it without removing it from the array? Also, it's not really clear, what you want to achieve with your code. What's the expected result from, say, the array of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`?

Comment: You should watch demystifying SwiftUI ranges are considered unsafe in SwiftUI you should not use them

Comment: @lazarevzubov Thanks for the tip, I now access the array elements by counting the index rather than removing them and it works. I still don’t really understand the issue with removing them though haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does *kind of* work on iOS 15 (but strangely - the order of the dice is unexpected), and crashes on iOS 16.  In general, you should not be using `var`s in SwiftUI view building code.

Your code can be modified to compute the index into the original `diceArray` from the `row`, `fullRows`, and `column` values:

```
struct DiceOnTableView: View {
    let diceArray: [Int]

    var body: some View {
        let fullRows: Int = diceArray.count / 3
        let diceInLastRow: Int = diceArray.count % 3

        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<fullRows, id: \.self) { row in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<3) { column in
                        Text("\(diceArray[row * 3 + column])")
                    }
                }
            }

            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<diceInLastRow, id: \.self) { column in
                    Text("\(diceArray[fullRows * 3 + column])")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ForEach` View will crash if you use it like a for loop with dynamic number of items. You need to supply it an array of item structs with ids, e.g. one that is `Identifiable`, e.g.

```
struct DiceItem: Identifable {
    let id = UUID()
    var number: Int
}

@State var diceItems: [DiceItem] = []

ForEach(diceItems) { diceItem in
```

And perhaps use a Grid instead of stacks.